# How can I rotate a 3D array in c#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, rotation

I have a binary object in a 3d array located in the origin (0,0,0). I need rotate this object dinamically in z axis. How can I rotate that multidimensional array with no fixed size in any angle?

I have created a 3d Point Class:

```
public class Point3
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

I'm thinking in do a foreach in each point and rotate it:

```
foreach (Point3 p in listPoint3)
{
    RotatePoint(p, angle);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "that multidimensional array with no fixed size". You're using "that" as if you're referring to something well described earlier. Please clarify what "3d array" means. You don't need a primitive array with a rank of 3 just to store a design-time unknown number of vertices. Do you mean an imaginary constraining box centered  in the origin of space ? What do you mean by "binary object" ?

Comment: @EduardDumitru The multidimensional array could have any size, e.g. [10,20,40] or [40,35,70], have no fixed size. That its refering to the object, in the 3d array. And yes I'm imagining the object in the center of a space. Binary object means an array only with 0 or 1, to because an array its only a cube but inside it I could draw anything.

Comment: So the 3d primitive array contains 0s and 1s and 1 means that there is something there and 0 means that there is nothing there. Did I get it right ? In case I got that right, are you aware that nobody understands that from your question ? Furthermore, in case I got it right, that is a bit "DENSE". You're storing a 3d shape in a non-vectorial way and that's naturally gonna cause a lot of problems. You could rotate such an object but you will loose resolution (a lot). Why did you create the `Point3` class (that is better). What is the connection between your 3d matrix and `Point3` ?

Comment: @EduardDumitru Yes, you are right with the 0 and 1. About the 3d array, i'm using it because each field in the array I know if its in or out, so I want ot get all coordinates and and rotate, for my 0 and 1 get the right angle. Could you help me in the question to be more understandable? I'm not very good in english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know what axis you want to rotate on. But if this is only a question where to look at. *(namespace System.Windows.Media.Media3D)*

You can try this:

```
double angle = 45;

RotateTransform3D zrotation = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(
                                  new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), angle));

foreach (Point3D p in listPoint3)
{
    Point3D rotatedPoint = zrotation.Transform(p);
}
```

You should use the build-in `Point3D`

Also if you want to Stack those: *(multiple transforms)*

```
double zAngle = 45;
double xAngle = 10;

Transform3DGroup group = new Transform3DGroup();
group.Children.Add( new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), xAngle)));
group.Children.Add( new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), zAngle)));

foreach (Point3D p in listPoint3)
{
    Point3D rotatedPoint = group.Transform(p);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You colud create a routine to rotate each point using the parametric equation for rotate the 3d object.

x' = x*cos(o)-y*sin(o)

y' = y*sin(o)-y*cos(o)

z' = z

```
private Point3 RotatePoint(Point3 p0, int angle)
{
    Point3 p =  new Point3()
    {
        X = p0.X * Math.Cos(angle) - p0.Y * Math.Sin(angle),
        Y = p0.X * Math.Sin(angle) + p0.Y * Math.Cos(angle),
        Z = p0.Z,
    };

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have a "monochrome object" which is stored like a 3D bitmap which you want to rotate around the Z axis. You must first understand that after a number of rotations you will end up with optical aberrations caused by the fact that you're using an `array index` which is a natural number to represent a coordinate of an object's component.

Upon rotation, any integer value will most likely become an irrational number. The fact that traditionally (not talking about special programs and frameworks) people store approximations of irrational numbers in `double` or `float` or `decimal` variables (which can only store a small subset of the rational numbers set) is **nothing** compared to the approximation of an irrational number by storing it in an integer (an `array index`).

Furthermore, even if that quality loss if of no big importance in the case of your application, you must be sure you understand that mathematically speaking, after a number of rotations, your 3d shape will be trimmed by the cylinder which is inscribed in the original parallelepiped, alongside the Z axis.

It goes like this. You said you already made a class called `Point3`:

```
public class Point3 {
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe you should follow @Jeroen van Langen's advice and use a standard class, if such a class already exists. The benefit would be that if someone out there already built or will ever build a library which uses that class you can start using the library right away.
But that's not so important right now.

@Alpert already gave a great C# code for rotating a point around the oZ axis. This is n "extension method" adaption of that code:

```
public static class RotationHelpers {

    public static Point3 RotatePoint(this Point3 point, int angle) {
        var result = new Point3() {
            X = point.X * Math.Cos(angle) - point.Y * Math.Sin(angle),
            Y = point.X * Math.Sin(angle) + point.Y * Math.Cos(angle),
            Z = point.Z,
        };
        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can go even further and make an extension method which rotates a sequence of points around the oZ axis:

```
public static class RotationHelpers {

    ...

    public static IEnumerable<Point3> RotatePoints(this IEnumerable<Point3> points, int angle) {
        foreach (var point in points)
            yield return point.RotatePoint(angle);
    }

    ...

}
```

Now you said you have a 3d primitive matrix with 1s and 0s in it:

```
int[,,] matrix;
```

You need to somehow convert the intrinsically defined points in that matrix into a sequence of `Point3` instances, rotate those and then convert the resulting sequence back into an `int[,,]` matrix.

That *could* be achieved like so (remember about the loss of quality I was talking about earlier):

```
public static class RotationHelpers {

    ...

    public static IEnumerable<Point3> ToPoints(this int[,,] matrix) {
        int lx = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int ly = matrix.GetLength(1);
        int lz = matrix.GetLength(2);

        for (int x = 0; x < lx; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < ly; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < lz; z++) {

            bool is1 = matrix[x, y, z] != 0;    
            if (is1)
                yield return new Point3 {
                    X = x - lx / 2,
                    Y = y - ly / 2,
                    Z = z - lz / 2
                };

        }
    }

    ...

}
```

That will take all of the cells in the WIDTH x HEIGHT x DEPTH matrix and for every cell which is not equal to 0 it will yield a new `Point3` instance with the coordinates of that particular position.

That sequence can then be rotate by an angle using the earlier described `RotatePoints` method and then the following method could be used to "render" back the resulting sequence of `Point3` instances into the array:

```
public static class RotationHelpers {

    ...

    public static void AssignPoints(this int[,,] matrix, IEnumerable<Point3> points) {
        int lx = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int ly = matrix.GetLength(1);
        int lz = matrix.GetLength(2);

        for (int x = 0; x < lx; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < ly; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < lz; z++)
            matrix[x, y, z] = 0;

        foreach (var point in points) {
            // this is when quality is lost, because things like 1.7 and 1.71
            // will both become =2

            var x = (int)Math.Round(point.X) + lx / 2;
            var y = (int)Math.Round(point.Y) + ly / 2;
            var z = (int)Math.Round(point.Z) + lz / 2;

            // this is where you loose parts of the object because
            // it doesn't fit anymore inside the parallelepiped
            if ((x >= 0) && (y >= 0) && (z >= 0) &&
                (x < lx) && (y < ly) && (z < lz))
                matrix[x, y, z] = 1;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

To wrap it up, you can use all of these methods like so:

```
int[,,] matrix = ...
int angle = ...

IEnumerable<Point3> points = matrix.ToPoints();
IEnumerable<Point3> rotatedPoints = points.RotatePoints(angle);

matrix.AssignPoints(rotatedPoints);
// now you have the original matrix, rotated by angle
```